# How does Out of Order execution work with conditional instructions, Ex: CMOVcc in Intel or ADDNE (Add not equal) in ARM

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, micro-architecture

I know they can only correctly execute after instructions before them in Re-Order Buffer are committed. My doubt is, do modern processors hold them till they are last in ROB or do any prediction counters/structures are used even for predicting the flag values like, Zero flag, or Carry flag, and then redo them if they were mispredicted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know they can only correctly execute after instructions before them in Re-Order Buffer are committed.

No, they only need their own inputs to be ready: those specific previous instructions *executed*, not retired / committed.

Conditional-move instructions (and ARM predicated execution) treat the flags input as a *data* dependency, just like add-with-carry, or just like an integer input register.  The conditional instruction can't be sent to an execution unit until all 3 of its inputs are ready<sup>1</sup>.  (Or on ARM, flags + however many inputs the predicated instruction normally has.)

Unlike with control dependencies (branches), **they don't predict or speculate what the flags will be**, so a `cmovcc` instead of a `jcc` can create a loop-carried dependency chain and end up being worse than a predictable branch.  [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) is an example of that.

Linus Torvalds explains in more detail why cmov often sucks: https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html

(ARM predicated execution might be handled slightly differently.  It has to logically NOP the instruction, even for a load or store to an invalid address.  This might be handled with just fault suppression for conditional loads.  I don't know if an instruction with a false predicate still costs any latency in the dependency chain for the destination register.)

---

Footnote 1: This is why `cmovcc` and `adc` are 2 uops on Intel before Broadwell: a single uop couldn't have 3 input dependencies.  Haswell introduced support for 3-input uops for FMA.

`cmov` instructions that read CF and one of the SPAZO flags (i.e. `cmova` and `cmovbe` which read CF and ZF) are actually still 2 uops on Skylake.  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867597/what-is-a-partial-flag-stall) for detail: it seems that those two separately-renamed groups of flags are both separate inputs, avoiding flag-merging.  See also https://uops.info/ for uop counts.

See also http://agner.org/optimize/, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more about x86 microarch details, and optimization guides.

Comment: Agner Fog in his [instruction table](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) mentions that `CMOVcc r,r` comprises `1 uop` on `Broadwell+`, but 2 uops on `Haswell-`. On my `KbL i7-8550U` however perf counters suggest that it comprises 2 uops. I suppose it was a typo.

Comment: @St.Antario: Were you using `cmova` or `cmovbe`?  Those are still 2 uops because they read both CF and a flag from the SPAZO cluster (specifically ZF).  Other CMOV instructions are single uop.  See https://uops.info/  See also [What is a Partial Flag Stall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49867597) for SKL details.