# imul then mov vs mov then imul - any difference?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

If I compile the following C++ program:

```
int baz(int x) { return x * x; }
```

in clang 15, I get:

```
baz(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
```

while gcc 12.2 gives me:

```
baz(int):
        imul    edi, edi
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

(See this on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WT4MThbcT))

Are these two implementations entirely equivalent, and merely a matter of arbitrary choice? If they're not equivalent, how can their difference manifest, or affect my program? I mean, in terms of CPU-state side-effects, latencies of other instructions, behavior during inlining etc.

Answer (score 5):

Do `mov` then `imul` because it's better with mov-elimination, and not worse anywhere for any other reason.

This is true in general for `mov`/`and`, `mov`/`sub`, etc, as long as you don't have a use for the original value.  If you do, then sometimes `mov` to make a copy and then modify the original to hide `mov` latency for CPUs without move elimination.  (`mov`/`add` or small shift should normally be `lea`).

#### CPU with [mov-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all)

**`mov` then `imul` is strictly better**; overwriting a `mov reg,reg` result lets Intel CPUs free some resources they use to track mov elimination.  (Probably something like a reference count for extra references beyond the normal RAT.)  This increases the likelihood of later mov-eliminations being successful.  See *[How do *move elimination* slots work in Intel CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204302/how-do-move-elimination-slots-work-in-intel-cpu)*

All else essentially equal (as in this case), prefer to `mov` then overwrite its result, especially when that doesn't make things worse for CPUs without mov-elimination (like Ice Lake, thanks Intel.)

It doesn't have to be in the next instruction, just sometime soon, preferably not left indefinitely e.g. for a long-running loop.  But even that isn't a disaster usually.

To measure this benefit, a microbenchmark would probably need to do a lot of `mov` instructions that *don't* overwrite their result, to run the CPU out of mov-elimination slots and have some of them need an execution unit.  The microbenchmark would also need to be sensitive to the *latency* of those `mov` instructions, since most modern Intel CPUs have enough execution units to keep up with the issue/rename width in terms of throughput.

#### CPU without mov-elimination

`mov reg,reg` has 1 cycle latency.  If you'd been doing `x*y` with two separate inputs, `mov` then `imul` makes that latency part of the input->output latency for one input but not the other.  The other has an extra cycle to become ready before the `imul` would have to wait for it, if out-of-order exec would tend to have one input ready before the other.

(A compiler would typically have no way to guess which input was the result of a long dep chain vs. a `mov`-immediate when compiling a non-inline function, but a 50/50 chance of winning a cycle is better than having the `mov` *always* on the critical path after the `imul`.)

But with `x*x` without mov-elimination, the only difference is that we're writing both EDI and EAX, instead of writing EAX twice.  I don't think that's significant in terms of using up physical-register-file (PRF) entries or freeing them sooner.  Since most code-gen is trying to be good across multiple CPUs, favour mov then imul because some CPUs do have mov-elimination.  It's essentially a tie for CPUs without, when you're squaring one variable.

---

#### Things that *don't* matter

On a CPU that does partial register renaming, writing a register might free up two physical-register-file (PRF) entries instead of just one.  (While allocating a new PRF entry either way.)  **But just reading the full register would already insert a merging uop.**

Intel Sandybridge-family is the only x86-64 microarchitecture that does partial-register renaming *and* uses a PRF.  Intel P6 family (Nehalem and earlier) keeps results right in the ROB, associated with the uop that produced them, until commit to a separate "retirement register file"; this is why it has register-read stalls when you read too many "cold" registers.  Only Sandybridge itself (and possibly Ivy Bridge) rename low-8 registers like DIL and DL separate from full registers; [on Haswell/Skylake and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) only high-8 registers like DH get renamed separately.

Anyway, DIL might have been renamed separately from the full RDI.   There is no DIH equivalent of DH or CH, since we're talking about EDI not EDX or ECX (the next two arg-passing registers), and gcc/clang very rarely generate code that writes high-8-bit registers.  (*[Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)*)

But either mov/imul or imul/mov will merge DIL into RDI before EDI is read, whether it's written or not (by the same imul uop).  Same for DH on Haswell and later if we had an arg in EDX.

Comment: "as long as you don't have a use for the original value" <- That's almost meaningless, in the sense that the function has an ABI which involves the input being placed in edi. The compiler can't know what gets placed there and whether it has any other use. That's a consideration for "inter-procedural" optimization passes. Of course, there's the question of whether the compiler is able to reverse the order of the operations when inlining the code later on.

Comment: @einpoklum: yes, meaningless in a function that does `return x*x;` rather than `foo = x*x;` / `bar = x-y;` or something.  I was considering the general case of needing mov+operation as part of a larger expression or in general in a larger function, since in practice you'd of course never want to have a function this tiny if you could possibly get it to inline.  Compilers do inlining much earlier than asm code-gen, so it's not a matter of "reversing" the order; GCC wouldn't have turned GIMPLE (SSA form) into RTL (register transfer language) until after inlining, same for LLVM using LLVM-IR.