# How to zero certain bytes of a register?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, x86-64, micro-optimization

Consider the following C functions:

```
int clear_byte0(int x)
{
    return x & 0xFFFFFF00;
}

int clear_byte1(int x)
{
    return x & 0xFFFF00FF;
}

int clear_bytes01(int x)
{
    return x & 0xFFFF0000;
}
```

They use the bitwise-and operator to clear out specific bits of an integer value.

The x86 architecture has partial registers, which can be zeroed to achieve the same purpose (e.g. `clear_byte0` can be implemented by zeroing `al`, assuming that `x` is stored in `eax`). However, it may not always be optimal to do so. Compilers disagree on the most optimal way to implement these functions, as shown in this [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/nj8417M1E) (GCC, clang and MSVC).

Clang and MSVC don't use partial registers at all, and instead mimic the C code, using an `and` instruction. They do differ in that clang first moves to `eax`, then `and`s, while MSVC first `and`s and then moves to `eax` (does it make a difference?).

GCC chooses to zero the partial registers for all 3 of the functions, by `xor`-ing `al`, `ah` and `ax`, respectively. Is this better or worse than using `and`? Can it cause partial register stalls, or the insertion of additional merging uops later on?

Another peculiarity in GCC's behavior is [the way it zeroes the "high 8" register](https://godbolt.org/z/3r7K4o648) (`ah`). In most cases, it uses `xor ah, ah` which is consistent with everything else. However, for some reason, when the source register is `ecx` or `edx` (probably `ebx` too), meaning it has access to `ch`/`dh`, it insists on using `mov eax, ecx`-`xor ah, ch` (instead of `xor ah, ah`). Does this mean that `xor reg8, reg8` has a penalty if the source and destination are the same?

Which one of these ways is the most optimal (and for which architectures)?

Comment: What do you think the performance difference between these ways are?  How small would it have to be for it not to matter?

Comment: @ScottHunter the question is purely theoretical. It's not a performance problem which I faced and narrowed down to this. I accidentally stumbled across code generated by GCC which uses `ah`, which is usually avoided because those registers have all sorts of penalties such as the insertion of merging uops.

Comment: [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502) / [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139) - `mov ah,0` and `xor ah,ah` are both 2-byte instructions with a false dependency on the destination on Skylake.

Comment: MOV then AND is slightly more optimal, freeing up extra tracking resources for mov-elimination and allowing a shorter encoding for `and eax, imm32`.  [How do \*move elimination\* slots work in Intel CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75204302) has some details from Intel's manual.  `mov eax, imm32` / `and eax, ecx` would be even better, only 1 c critical-path latency and still short machine code.

Comment: (In my last comment, I meant `mov eax, mask` / `and eax, reg` has shorter critical path latency for CPUs without mov-elimination for GPRs, such as Ice Lake with updated microcode, or Bulldozer-family, or Sandybridge or earlier Intel.  But it has a downside of 2 uops that need an execution unit, potentially worse on CPUs that *do* have mov-elimination if nearly bound on back-end ports.)